# jquery JSON remove separators from query strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to use the [Jquery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) to retrieve synonyms for any word using a [Thesaurus API](http://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php).

I need to make a following json GET request to access the API

```
http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/{version}/{api key}/{word}/{format}
```

Jquery however generates the following which returns a `404 Not Found`

```
http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/?v=2&key=mykey&word=some-word&format=json
```

Is it possible to easily remove the separators?

**Script**

```
$(function() {
        function log( message ) {
            $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
            $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
        }

        $( "#thesaurus" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        v: "2",
                        key: "mykey", //actually numbers
                        word: request.term,
                        format: "json"
                        //maxRows: 12,
                        //name_startsWith: request.term
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item.name + (item.noun ? ", " + item.noun : "") + ", " + item.syn,
                                value: item.name
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            },
            open: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
            },
            close: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
            }
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
    <input id="thesaurus" />

</div>

<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
    Result:
    <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of the data parameter to the `$.ajax()` function is to create a query string (both POST and GET use query strings, they are just sent as different parts of the request payload). You just want to use simple string concatenation to build your URL.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/mykey/" + request.term + "/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function( data ) {
        response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
            return {
                label: item.name + (item.noun ? ", " + item.noun : "") + ", " + item.syn,
                value: item.name
            }
        }));
    }
});
```

You had static version, api key and format parameters but if they were dynamic, the url would look like:

```
"http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/" + version + "/" + api_key + "/" + request.term + "/" + format
```

To make your code a little cleaner you could even go as far as:

```
"http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/" + [version,api_key,request.term,format].join("/")
```

Comment: thank you! with this modification how would I change the `response()` part? is it still needed?

Comment: @CyberJunkie The `success` callback and your `response()` function call deal with the data returned from the api call.  Assuming you want to do something useful with the data the api returns you absolutely need them.  I don't know what your response function looks like or needs to do so I can't be more helpful than that.

Answer (score 1):

Move data into url:

```
    $( "#thesaurus" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/" + "mykey/" + request.term + "/json",
                ....
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
url:"http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/"
           +"2/"+encodeURIComponent(mykey)+"/"
           +encodeURIComponent(request.term)+"/json"),
```

And remove the `data` option.

Comment: Actually that wouldn't work. It would % encode the `/` so the final url would look like: `http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2%2F<mykey>%2F<request.term>%2Fjson` However, encoding the individual segments is probably a good idea.